# Azure App Service VNET Integration with Internal DNS

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-service, azure-load-balancer

I am looking to integrate my public app service to my production virtual network to gain access to some resources within it (APIs), some of which will be load balanced with internal load balancers (container services containers inside an AKS environment) - I would like to use a private DNS zone to attribute DNS names to the ILB IP addresses created by AKS so that my upstream app services need to only deal in Azure private DNS and I am free to change the IP address this DNS points to as an when required.

Firstly, is this possible? If so - how would I go about getting the app service to use the private DNS zone for resolution of resources within my VNET?

Alternatively... is there a better pattern I could follow here? I am ultimately wanting my upstream developers using public cloud app services to be able to reference the address for private VNET services in a DNS format (service1.mydns.private) instead of referencing internal load balancer IP addresses!

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Azure DNS Private Zones. You would need to specify the VNETs associated with your App Service, as well as the VNET where your ILB and other resources exist, as Resolution VNETs for the private zone (eg: myzone.local). Then, you create a DNS record for the ILB in the private zone (eg: myilb.myzone.local). Then, from your App Service, simply use the DNS record (eg: myilb.myzone.local) to name resolve the ILB IP.

Comment: I have about 2000 hostnames I need to resolve so should I go about adding one by one manually to that private DNS zone?

Comment: Below is a similar question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71945473/how-to-resolve-hostnames-in-azure-vnet-by-connecting-to-internal-hadoop-on-prem